# Gibbs free energy can be expressed as a function of P,T and n but are enthalpy and internal energy also (partially) functions of n?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

$$G=G(P,T,n)$$
$$\mathrm dG=V\,\mathrm dP-S\,\mathrm dT+\mu\,\mathrm  dn=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_{T,n}\,\mathrm dP+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P,n}\,\mathrm dT+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}\right)_{T,P}\,\mathrm dn$$

This allows open systems to be considered (where $\mathrm dn$ does not equal zero). However, can enthalpy, internal energy and Helmholtz free energy also be treated in this way to allow for open systems?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking.  Do you mean, is it as simple as adding a $(\frac {\partial X}{\partial n})dn$ term, where $X$ is the state function of interest?  In that case no .. for example, Helmholz free energy is *defined* as the useful work that can be obtained from a *closed* thermodynamic system at constant T.  The definition of Gibbs free energy includes the open nature of the system, and the state function has the corresponding "natural" thermodynamic variables, P,T and n.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. Why can't you do this for state functions like helmholtz free energy and enthalpy? Or perhaps it's more useful to think about the converse: why does gibbs free energy allow for an open system to be considered whilst enthalpy and so on do not?

Comment: Because that's specifically how it is defined.  Also, it's not that enthalpy (and other function) don't allow for open systems to be considered .. the enthalpy is part of the Gibbs free energy, after all.  It's more that open systems are not part of the natural definitions of those other state functions.  You can define the exact differential of helmholz free energy for an open systems .. you just add $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$, so the definition is still in terms of chemical potential, which relates to changes in the Gibbs free energy with composition.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the natural definitions? I don't see anything particularly different between $dG=VdP-SdT$ and $dH=TdS+VdP$ that would cause gibbs free energy to naturally take into account open systems. Also, on the note of just adding $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$ I mean add on the appropriate equivalent to $\mu$ molar enthalpy for example or molar helmholtz free energy.

Comment: What I mean is that the derivation of the Gibbs free energy was specifically done to include the effects of composition changes .. this is not true of the other functions.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#Derivation) for a short explanation of how the natural thermodynamic variables are obtained.  Regarding the other point, I understand .. that's why my original comment said "no, you can't just do that" ... you *can* still account for open systems, you just can't do it that way.

Comment: Thank you. Although it does show that one can do it for internal energy. Also, searching enthalpy in wikipedia I was able to find the expression that involved the $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$ term. With all due respect, are you absolutely sure you are right?

Comment: I am not sure why you seem to find my comments inconsistent.  I have said that you CAN account for the effects of open systems on thermodynamic state functions by adding $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$ to the exact differential.  I have also said (although not directly) that $\mu_i=(\frac {\partial G}{\partial n_i})_{T,P}$ is always the definition of the chemical potential.  I said you CANNOT add the analogous quantity $\sum_i(\frac {\partial A}{\partial n_i})_{T,V}dn_i$ to the exact differential of Helmholz free energy (for example) to allow for open systems.  Yes, I am sure that is all correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. However, why does adding a partial derivative of G work for the total derivatives of A or H? Thanks for your patience, I am sorry for all the questions.

Comment: I'm not completely certain (I actually hadn't thought about it that way), but I think it's because the natural variables of those other state functions include extensive properties, like volume, or entropy, that depend on the total number of particles in the system.  Thus when you add the $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$ term to the exact differential of one of the other state functions, it is not independent of the other terms.  For Gibbs free energy, the other natural variables are the intensive properties p and T, so the $n_i$ *are* independent variables.

Comment: I think I have made too much of the number of particles being a natural variable of ONLY the Gibbs free energy.  Actually, it is a natural variable of any thermodynamic potential (internal energy, enthalpy, Helmholtz free energy, or Gibbs free energy).  The more important consideration for your question is the intensive vs. extensive nature of the other state function variables.  I am working on a response to your other question on this topic that I hope makes this clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20129/discussion-between-dtmoore1971-and-robchem).

Comment: EVERYONE PLEASE DISREGARD MY OTHER COMMENTS ON THIS THREAD. I made a dumb mistake right at the start, and then compounded it on down the line.  I think we have it all sorted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define chemical potentials as partial molar enthalpies, or partial molar internal energies, or partial molar Helmholz free energies.  (Sorry for my initial confusion on this point ... see also my answer on your other question on this topic, [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23565/how-does-the-chemical-potential-allow-for-open-systems-to-be-considered/23567#23567)).

The definitions as partial molar enthalpies and partial molar internal energies are not particularly useful, since they involve working at constant entropy, which is practically impossible, but they are still mathematically valid.

The definition of chemical potential as partial molar Helmholz free energy at constant temperature and volume may actually have some practical applications, (e,g. perhaps for reactions that evolve gases in closed containers? although I have never come across any.

Comment: The definition $\mu_i = \left(\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{n_i}}\right)_{T,V,n_{j \neq i}}$ is very useful for gases in general - they are frequently described by equations of state (EoS) in (T,V,N)-coordinates (e.g. ideal gas law, SRK etc.), which makes Helmholtz free energy the most suitable thermodynamic potential. A practical example is the calculation of phase equilibria, but there are many others.